How to preserve the focus order when fields are rendered conditionally with RHF?
when I render inputs conditionally, the focus order is not preserved by RHF, in the following stackblitz you could see the error, to reproduce it you could follow these steps:

press submit button
the field firstname will be focused
fill the firstname input
press the add details checkbox, two new fields will be rendered gender and dateOfBirth
press again the submit button
the focus will be done into the lastname field instead of the gender input

What I expect is, that the focus respects the UI input order.
